# Drawing a conical mirror in pst-optexp

Tags: diagrams, pst-optexp

I need to draw an optical system which contains a conical mirror, which in the 2D projection is just a triangle or angled mirror. I would like to implement the drawing in `pst-optexp`. However, I don't see an option to have a polygon mirror, just flat, curved and parabolic ones. Of course I could just put two connected mirrors, but depending on the connection angle the graphical representation wouldn't be nice (extending line edges for acute angles). I'm new to `pst-optexp`, and maybe I have overseen the corresponding command.

The sketch below should illustrate the setup. I have two mirrors in my setup (in Green). The lower one is just a flat one, the upper one an angled one, which should reflect the light into two directions. In 3D this corresponds to a cone mirror as illustrated in the picture at the end.

[image: Setup with two mirrors]

[image: Picture of cone mirror]

Comment: Welcome into this community TeX.SE. Happy year. Can, please, explain better your question also with an example, with more information. Your question it is not very clear.

Comment: Happy new year! Thanks for your clarification question. In fact I just asked, if a mirror can be defined with another shape than flat, circular or parabolic. In my case I want to define it as polygon (or even just a triangle). Thanks ...

Comment: Hi, and happy new year also for you. Can you have a minimal example or just can you add a drawing to understood the question, please?

Comment: I have added an illustration. I hope that my question becomes more clear with that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no ready-to-use component for your task, but you can quite easily define your own component.

`pst-optexp` offers plain, curved and path interfaces (see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/209818/33933 for an advanced example).

Here are the main steps

1. Define a new component with `\newOptexpDipole{conicalmirror}`. You could also use `\newOptxpTripole`. The differences in your case would only be that you need two or three nodes for positioning.
2. Define the actual appearance of the component with `\def\conicalmirror@comp`
3. Define the optical interfaces inside `\conicalmirror@nodes` using `\newOptexpComp`. Here, we use a `PathIfc`, which takes a previously defined, arbitrary path as interface using `pst-intersect`.

The full drawing:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-optexp}
\SpecialCoor
\makeatletter
% Define a custom dipole command
\newOptexpDipole{conicalmirror}
%
% Define how the dipole component is drawn
\def\conicalmirror@comp{%
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=gray,linestyle=none](1,-1)(0,0)(1,1)(2,1)(2,-1)
  \pspolygon[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=green!50!black,linestyle=none]%
    (1,-1)(1.1,-0.9)(0.2,0)(1.1,0.9)(1,1)(0,0)
}
% Define the optical interfaces of the component
\def\conicalmirror@nodes{%
  % save the path, a triangle, which defines the optical interface
  \pssavepath[linestyle=none]{\oenode@Path{A}}{%
    \psline(1,-1)(0,0)(1,1)}
  % define the optical interface for use to draw beams
  \newOptexpComp{%
    {0 0} tx@IntersectDict /\PIT@name{\oenode@Path{A}} get 0 0 refl {PathIfc} 1
  }%
}%
\makeatother
      
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(10,6)
  \pnode(0,1){Input}
  \pnode(5,1){Mirror}
  \pnode(5,4){ConicalMirror}
  \pnode(2,4){End1}
  \pnode(8,4){End2}
  \begin{optexp}
    \lens[lens=3 3 2, n=1.6, compname=Lens](Input)(Mirror)
    \newpsstyle{ExtendedMirror}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=green!50!black}
    \mirror[mirrorwidth=3, linestyle=none, mirrordepth=0.1414, mirrortype=extended, compname=Mirror](Input)(Mirror)(ConicalMirror)
    \conicalmirror[position=end, compname=ConicalMirror](Mirror)(ConicalMirror)
    \optplate[position=end, plateheight=3, platelinewidth=0.3, compshift=-0.5, compname=End1](ConicalMirror)(End1)
    \optplate[position=end, plateheight=3, platelinewidth=0.3, compshift=0.5, compname=End2](ConicalMirror)(End2)
    %
    % First, only draw the filled beam, otherwise the fillings overlap with boundary beams
    \newpsstyle{Beam}{fillstyle=solid, fillcolor=red!10, linestyle=none}
    \drawwidebeam[beamdiv=20, beamangle=-10.01](Input){Lens}{Mirror}{ConicalMirror}{End1}
    \drawwidebeam[beamdiv=20, beamangle=10.01](Input){Lens}{Mirror}{ConicalMirror}{End2}
    %
    % now draw the boundary beams
    \newpsstyle{Beam}{linecolor=red, linewidth=0.5\pslinewidth}
    \drawbeam[beamangle=20](Input){Lens}{Mirror}{ConicalMirror}{End2}
    \drawbeam[beamangle=0.01](Input){Lens}{Mirror}{ConicalMirror}{End2}
    \drawbeam[beamangle=-0.01](Input){Lens}{Mirror}{ConicalMirror}{End1}
    \drawbeam[beamangle=-20](Input){Lens}{Mirror}{ConicalMirror}{End1}
  \end{optexp}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]